# Searching for a website that will calculate gematria and indicate parts of torah that match that numerical value

Tags: internet, product-recommendation, gematria-numerology

Many years ago I went to a website that had a Gematria calculator. You could type in any hebrew word and it would tell you the numerical value of the word. Then, it would show you any words or consecutive series of words in Tanach that matched the numerical value of the word you put in. It would show you the whole passuk with the matching word(s) highlighted.

I can't remember the name of the site and I couldn't find it on Google. Does anyone know of a website that does this? Extra points if the website you point to is the one I remembered.

Comment: My virus detection program detected viruses on all of the links provided below in the answers

Comment: http://secretorah.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing [this gematria search tool](http://thetrugmans.com/word-and-gematria-search/) on Ohr Chadash. The one thing I wish the tool had is a way to put in a number directly and search for strings that match, but you can get that effectively by expressing that number in letters. It just takes a lot of tavs sometimes.

Comment: That isn't the site I remember, but it does what I'm looking for. One downside is that it is a flash interface, but the text is selectable, which is a good.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using a great program called Gematriel 2.0 (גימטריאל) by Dr. Raphael Polyakov available here: http://raphael.eu.pn/gematriel/. It lets you enter both text and numbers and has a full Torah text too.

Comment: Jason, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the suggestion. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1508/jason), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

If I may toot my own horn, I created just such a website as this question addresses. The website consists of only 3 "pages": 
1) A Home Page, with the methods of search to choose from;
2) An Options Page, that provides the options of that method you chose;
3) A Results Page, or your "Hit list", listing all the matches.
Doing it this way, and keeping global variables on the Home Page, this website I hope is intuitive or user-friendly.
It's always in development because I'm just a one-man (retired) operation and when I feel like it or think of something new, I'll dabble in its further development. Thankfully I now have the whole Tanach as the database. All that other "gematria sites" can do, this one can do better.

The website sits behind a yeshiva firewall so you must type in the "http://" instead of the "www." (**http://toraware.com**)

A next stage of development will be to convert it to an app, but my knowhow there suffers. (I'd love some help if someone wants to volunteer.)

Other future things I might do is: Expand the database to include the Kri version. Right now it's the Ksiv version only. If someone can think of other paradigms of search, do please let me know. If it's good, I'll love to develop it.

You can follow my developmental process because I record my progress, as I go along, on this blog: **torawaredotcom.blogspot.com**

Comment: Someone did mention you before

Comment: I am only sorry that on this page we have a link to a non-Jewish site that searches the non-original "bible", which hazoriz below brings. I'd think in a place of Torah this is inappropriate, even though he has only good intentions.

Comment: I’ve visited the sites mentioned here, namely:
1) http://thetrugmans.com/word-and-gematria-search/,
2) http://raphael.eu.pn/gematriel/,
3) and a gentile site
and find mine (the 4th) - http://toraware.com - by far the best of the bunch. After all, it took me many many years to perfect and streamline and make user-friendly. Just as Google made things simple but powerful, I followed suit providing simplicity but accuracy and options for each search method. (Be sure to use prefix http://)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this site http://toraware.com/ for searching gematrias and ESL - outcomes such as shown [here](https://geula613.blogspot.com/2017/06/name-analysis-of-convert.html) and I am very happy with this program.

Answer (score 1):

We are developing a web site and program that calculates both Equidistant Letter Sequences (ELS) Torah Bible Codes as well as Gematria values.

http://TorahBibleCodes.com

https://github.com/TorahBibleCodes