# Acronym for ה׳תש״ע

Tags: calendar, acronyms

I know that every Hebrew year has one or more acronym for it. What acronyms do we use for the year ה׳תש״ע?
Google is not helping me.

Comment: Could you be clearer, please?  What do you mean by an acronym for a year?

Comment: Also, are you asking about 5770, or did you mean 5774?

Comment: For instance תשע״ב i know stands for: תהא שנת עליה ברוכניות (spelling may be off) which roughly translated means "this is a year of upwards in godliness.

Comment: And specifically 5770 ה׳תש״ע

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman A common phenomenon, particularly among Lubavitch, is to link a year to a portentive acronym. I read that the Rebbe began this trend in 5742 with תהא שנת ביאת משיח.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on "we". There's no official backronym, and some years have differing ones depending on whom you ask. If there's a specific "we" you have in mind, you may wish to [edit] that into your question so you get the answers you seek. Anyway, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: Not any particular we. I was asked to find a good one for a book my family is publishing, so all suggestions are welcome, and my family will pick the one they like most.

Comment: @fred. Where did u read that? Id like to look it up, as its very interesting and might be very useful.

Comment: If your interest is book publishing, you may not be looking for an acronym from the year. Popular practice when publishing books was to take a phrase or verse whose numerical value was the same as the year and present that as the year. Some fudging was allowed and usually the relevant letters were in bold. See an example here: http://hebrewbooks.org/19100

Comment: The verse or phrase usually had some connection to either the book or author. Perhaps some of the gematria tools in this question can help you find a relevant phrase or verse: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9437/603

Comment: Anyone can make up an acronym based on the year letters. 5773 ended with a situation suited to תגע"ש and 5774 can be written שתד"ע - however, whether there is any real meaning to this only Hashem knows.

Comment: Greetings @MenachemRoetter!  If it would help you, consider joining the petition for a [Hebrew Language learners site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage) — although please always feel free to bring your questions here, too!

Comment: Re "I was asked to find a good one for a book my family is publishing, so all suggestions are welcome": So you're not looking for acronyms that have been used but simply for *any* acronym for 5770? That's [a very broad question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

תהא שנת עוז, עליון, עליה, ענוה, עלצון

Comment: Thanx! Can u transelate them please?

Comment: Atzlus is laziness